# setInterval Not Repeating Function using Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot that gives you ***weekly reminders***. Im using `momentjs` to get the time. As well as using `discord.js-commando`. I found the best way to call a function multiple times is to use `setInterval`.

```js
const moment = require('moment');
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const bot = new Commando.Client();

bot.on('ready', function () {
  var day = moment().format('dddd');
  var time = moment().format('h:mm a');

  function Tuesday() {
    if (day == 'Tuesday' && time == '6:30 pm') {
      const channel = bot.channels.get('933047404645724234');
      console.log('Sending Message');
      channel.send('Reminder: You have a week to complete your To-Do List!');
    } else {
      console.log('Not Sending Message');
    }
  }

  console.log('Bot is now ready!');
  setInterval(Tuesday, 100);
});
```

I noticed the problem with the `setInterval` is that it is only called once. I also tried using an async function but that failed as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well executing a function every 100ms is not quite optimal. I don't know what is the reason to run just once (it should run infinitely) but there is a better way to do what you need.

You will need the package called "node-schedule". It's really useful for such things.

Here's an example:

```js
const schedule = require("node-schedule");

schedule.scheduleJob({hour: 18, minute: 30, dayOfWeek: 2}, function(){
    // your code here
});
```

You can read more in the documentation of node-schedule [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule).